# Why my python cannot read files on my desktop?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm new here and in python. There are 2 questions I'd like to ask:
1) I'm reading a .dat file on my desktop into my spider, but it shows

> No such file or directory: 'C:\Desktop\movies.dat'

but if I put the file into the default folder, `'C:\\Users\\User\\.spyder-py3\\movies.dat'`, it can read the file successfully. I thought that python3 can file the path in the quotes no matter if it is a default folder or not.
2) I've been reading some python books and at every beginning of each book, there is a chapter introducing Ipython and Jupyter or something like that, I don't quite understand what's the difference between, like, Anaconda, Spider, Jupyter notebook and Ipython. I'm currently using Spider and wondering what's the difference.

Great thanks if anyone can help!

Answer (score 0):

in my first view you can't read the 'C:\Desktop\movies.dat' because the path it's no complete ? Or try something like this

```
from pathlib import Path

data_folder = Path("C:\Desktop")
file_to_open = data_folder / "movies.dat"

f = open(file_to_open)
print(f.read())
```

For the second question, Ancaconda, Jupyter and Spider are python frameworks you can read more about them at [What is the difference between spyder and jupyter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53368253/what-is-the-difference-between-spyder-and-jupyter)